# Don't let users reboot while root's logged in

Tags: shutdown, reboot

On my system users can reboot and shut down the system. From time to time I need to update software (or do anything else) and I don't want users to reboot/shutdown the system until I've finished.

Is there a way to prevent system from rebooting/shutting down while root is logged in (locally or over SSH)?

Comment: How will you ever prevent people from using the brute force method?

Comment: @Bernhard probably something with `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`

Answer (score 11):

Try Molly guard:

```
$ sudo apt-get install molly-guard
```

This package will prevent unintended shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate by interactively prompting you to enter the hostname of the system.

However, it's trivial to configure molly-guard to completely disable shutdown/reboot/suspend/hibernate. Simply create an executable file at /etc/molly-guard/run.d/99-prevent-all that has this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 1
```

(You didn't mention the OS, this is for Ubuntu).

#### History

If you're curious the term molly-guard is what the cover over a red button is called. See the wikipedia article on [Big Red Button](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_red_button) if you're curious.

*excerpt*

> A Big Red Switch often includes a molly-guard, a cover that must be lifted to trip the switch. The original molly-guard was jury-rigged from Plexiglas to prevent a programmer's young daughter Molly from pressing the BRS on an IBM 4341 server, after she had done so twice in one day.

#### Other distros

You can take the `.deb` package and use `alien` to convert it to an RPM suitable for Fedora/RHEL/CentOS.

```
$ sudo yum install alien
$ alien -r molly-guard*.deb
```

Comment: +1 never heard of this tool, will be installing it on several serers 8-).

Comment: Really neat tool.  For the sake of the specific question and completeness, might specify for root's .bashrc / .bash_logout to enable/disable the all-stop.  A conditional in the molly-guard script checking for UID!=0 might also be appropriate.